# Elasticsearch - tokenize terms by capitalized character, for example "TheStarTech" => [The, Star, Tech]

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

Does Elasticsearch support tokenizer to tokenize terms by capitalized character, for example: Tokenize `TheStarTech` to terms `[The, Star, Tech]`. [Pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html#analysis-pattern-tokenizer) seems helpful, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [World Delimited Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html)

It does what you want and more. You can pass in the parameters as may fit your need. Check `split_on_case_change` parameter which is true by default.

Comment: Do you have idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716832/elasticsearch-combine-terms-into-one